# Code coverage issue for apex code with countless run options

Tags: code-coverage

We have a custom-developed price calculator which covers so many possible run options that make it hardly impossible to include all possible calculation options in a test class, hence minimal code coverage cannot be reached.
The options are all based on either flags in a record or either or not existance of related records, in many different combinations (so really no hardcoded apex things).
Any suggestion on how to handle this ?

Comment: At present you have the issue that there is no proof that your calculator works.  The main purpose of tests is to establish that the code works today, and to protect you in future when changes are made that you don't accidentally break anything. (Coverage is an indicator not a goal in itself.) So I think you should just go ahead and write the tests (designing the code as best you can to avoid code duplication). If you have manually tested the code use those test scenarios in your test methods.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, I would like to see other people's opinions about this as well.

I would try to find some common scenarios/rules that can't be broken in different configurations. For example, if it is always required to have some lookup field set, I would test that. Another example, if there are some Date related business rules that can't be broken across different combinations.

Another nice thing for tests is to assert that **wrong** conditions **will fail**, people often forget about this. Only testing that the correct/expected behavior works can bring you some unpleasant surprises.

But when you say **price calculator** it sounds like a core feature to me. That means it is very good to have it well tested. And if it is too hard to test, maybe you should rethink the way it is implemented.